# Does the proton do anything in a simple electric DC circuit?

Tags: electricity, electrons, protons

Since the valence or free electrons and doing the flowing guided by electromagnetic field, what about the protons that are still stuck in the nucleus inside the wire, battery, resistor what have you those protons are they doing any work at all?

Comment: Various devices use ions to transport current. And of course ion currents in accelerators are quite common.

Comment: In semiconductors, it is common for positively charged holes to carry current. The best visualization I have seen for that is in Veritasium's latest video [Why It Was Almost Impossible to Make the Blue LED](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AF8d72mA41M)

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that electrons are the majority charge carriers in metallic conductors, which make up most of the current path in a typical electric circuit. But not all conductors are metallic. In pure water (which isn't a very good conductor, but where the chemistry is easy to understand), there is a small constant population of $\rm H^+$ and $\rm OH^-$ ions. Both of these are charge carriers, but the hydrogen ions are less massive and therefore more mobile.

In other electrolytes, the majority charge carriers may be positive or negative depending on the chemistry. So whether there are positive charge carriers in a circuit may depend on the battery chemistry.

A comment mentions conduction by "holes" in the electron population of some semiconductors. Conceptually this is sort of like asking whether an upside-down bottle drains because the water flows down, or because the air bubbles flow up. But there are some sneaky quantum-mechanical features of semiconductors that annoy the intuitions of many semiclassical thinkers (including me). A hole-doped semiconductor really does have positive mobile charge carriers, even though if you took it apart you would have stationary positive ions and a gas of negative electrons; collective phenomena are weird.